# How to find the velocity after a collision if one or more of the bodies has a spring attached to it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

A body with mass of $m$ $kg$ ($A$) is sliding horizontally in a frictionless surface at the velocity, $V_0$.

In front of it are two bodies ($B$ and $C$) , each with a mass of $m$ $kg$ attached with a spring whose force constant is $k$.

If the collision between $A$ and $B$ is elastic,  how to calculate the velocities of A,B and C after the collision?

[image: Before the collision]

I took $a$,$b$ and $c$ respectively as velocities of $A$,$B$ and $C$ after the collision.

Using C.O.L.M

$mv_0 = ma + mb + mc$

$v_0 = a + b + c$

Using C.O.M.E
$$\frac{1}{2}m{v_0}^2 = \frac{1}{2}m{a}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m{b}^2 +\frac{1}{2}m{c}^2$$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B$ and $C$ are attached with a spring, we can take those as one object and find the velocity of the system's center of mass. Therefore, by utilizing the conservation of linear momentum and mechanical energy, we can obtain;
$$
m\vec v_0 = m\vec a + 2m\vec d
$$
$$
\vec v_0 = \vec a + 2\vec d
$$
$$
\left|\vec v_0\right|= 2\left|\vec d\right| - \left|\vec a\right|  
$$
$$
{\left|\vec v_0\right|}^2 = {\left|\vec a\right|}^2 + 2{\left|\vec d\right|}^2
$$
where $\vec d$ is the velocity vector of the center of mass of $BC$ system after the collision. By solving these, you can obtain velocities of these objects and COM in terms of each other;
$$
\vec d=-2\vec a
$$
$$
\vec v_0=3\vec a
$$
If you want to find the velocities of both $B$ and $C$, my answer is they wouldn't have a constant velocity. Instead, they would make simple harmonic motion. Therefore, you can find their velocities at a specific time. Thus, we can write differential equations for both $B$ and $C$ and solve them to find their velocities. If we say the coordinates of $B$ and $C$ are $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, the equations would be;
$$
m\ddot x_1=-k(x_2-x_1-L)
$$
$$
m\ddot x_2=-k(x_1-x_2+L)
$$
where $L$ is the length of the spring at equilibrium state.

Comment: How can B and C taken as a single object? I mean the spring is compressed after the collision and there must be a relative velocity between B and C for that.Thus B & C should have different velocities, right?

Comment: @jessij I extended my answer. Hope this clears things up a bit.